# Два подхода к реализации REST API на Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Делаю REST API на Spring. Посмотрел курс по Spring Data Hibernate и обнаружил, что делал REST API наиболее трудоемким способом.

При добавлении новой сущности в домен я проходил следующую цепочку объектов:

1. Entity - доменный объект
2. DTO - для передачи/получения объекта на/с клиента
3. Mapper - для преобразования между Entity и DTO
4. Repository - для взаимодействия с БД
5. RestController - для обработки запросов к API
6. Service - сервисный класс для объекта

Приблизительная цепочка моих действий была следующая:

1. RestController обрабатывает запросы - получает DTO от клиента(в случае создания нового объекта)
2. Mapper в контроллере преобразует DTO в Entity
3. Вызывается Service
4. Service обращается к Repository
5. Repository возращает результат выполнения(созданный Entity)
6. Service возвращает в RestController созданный Entity
7. RestController возвращает клиенту объект типа ResponseEntity, куда я кладу тело и код ответа.

Как видите большая цепочка действий и большое количество объектов.

Но тут я выяснил, что если использовать Spring Data REST, то все это не нужно все API поставляется Spring из коробки. В общем случае требуется создать только Entity и Repository.

Получается, что для типовых операций типа CRUD я зря писал множество котроллеров и их методов.

Вопросы:

1. Когда необходимо использовать RestConroller, а когда Spring Data REST?
2. Можно ли совмещать два подхода для одной Entity?
   Получается, что я зря прописывал для простых операций create, get, save, delete контроллеры, это можно переложить на Spring Data REST.
3. Смогу ли я в Spring Data Rest реализовать некоторые действия, которые я сделал в RestConroller? Такие как:

   - Возврат значение свойства сущности в виде id, а не объекта?
     Т.е. у меня есть свойства у сущностей, которые сами являются сущностями, для таких полей мне иногда требуется возвращать их ID, а не всю сущность.
   - Можно ли как-то контролировать обработку ошибок? в RestController я реализовал класс расширяющий ResponseEntityExceptionHandler и все ошибки, где бы они не возникали в моих RestController обрабатываются однотипным образом в одном месте и я всегда знаю, что все ошибки вернут приблизительно одинаковую структуру ответа
   - Валидацию данных придется навешивать на сущности, раньше делал валидацию на получаемых от клиента DTO. Ждут ли меня в связи с этим какие-то нюансы?

Я немного в тупике, как двигаться дальше. Дайте свои рекомендации и размышления по этому поводу. Подтолкните к дальнейшим действиям, что использовать и как.

Comment: Тут явно применима аксиома Эскобара...

Comment: Всё очень просто... если вам достаточно веб-сервисов, которые генирируются спрингом, то Вы используете их. Если у Вас есть какая-то кастомная логика или своеобразное отображение сущностей, то Вы пилите это вручную. Совмещать можно, пока не конфликтуют адреса.